# How to update softlinks when folder is updated?

Tags: filesystem, directory, symbolic-link

I have two directories 'original' and 'soft'. 
I have soft links on all the files of the original directory.

```
ln -s original/* soft/
```

However, on the regular basis files are getting copied and deleted daily basis. However new links are not getting added as well as links of on the deleted files are not getting deleted.

How can I ensure that all the links get deleted when the file is deleted? and links get added when files are added.

PS: I don't want to achieve this with something like this `ln -s original/ soft`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to have soft itself be a symbolic link to original, then the most straightforward approach is to have a cron job that deletes all of the symbolic links in soft, and recreate the symbolic links based on what is in original.  Depending on the frequency of the updates, you could run that cron job every minute, every hour, every day, ...

Hope this helps.

Comment: It would help to add some detail, like how would you delete all the symbolic links, and what would the cron job look like? For the former, I'm thinking something like `find /path/to/original -type l -delete`.